# How to start/stop PHP webservice via Web Interface?

Tags: php, web-services, wamp

I want to build a `PHP web service` (preferably SOAP) that will be hosted in a local web server (currently I am using WAMP server). Now I want to build a web interface to start/stop this service (a simple web page with start and stop button).

The requirement is when I stop the web service, the other web applications consuming these web services should throw an error.

Is it possible at all? I did some R&D and my perception is that as long as the PHP files are accessible, the service can be consumed. One way is to stop the web server itself, but that is not possible in my case, as other web applications are also hosted in the same web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration, PHP isn't really running when requests aren't being made, so there's nothing to start or stop.  The thing you need to start or stop is the web server.

You should probably be separating your applications out anyway so that they can support multiple server configs.  A typical way to do this is to have a proxy out front (such as Nginx) which then proxies to back-end web servers running on other ports.  Then if you want to restart the web server for one application, the others aren't affected.

As far as doing that with a web interface... I recommend using an off-the-shelf tool for this.  If you want to do it yourself, you could always shell exec the appropriate commands from PHP.

Comment: Will it be possible to configure proxies in local servers like wamp? Also, can you please recommend some off-the-shelf tool that you mentioned?

Comment: Your server is Apache, not WAMP, and yes, you can configure Apache this way.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html  And for remote management, I have no recommendation.  I haven't had to remotely manage a Windows box outside of VNC over a VPN in years.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121765/free-affordable-remote-web-based-administration-for-windows-iis  Why are you using Apache anyway?  IIS is quite robust, performant, and works well with PHP.  If you were on Linux I'd recommend Nginx.

Comment: I am configuring all the things into a web server package that can be xcopy deployed into other machines without need of further configuration. In case of IIS, I have to do all the configuration in every machine. Unfortunately, I am on Windows environment only, so no linux alternative.

Comment: If you're running Apache as a service, that's no more or less configuration you're going to need anyway.  Besides, you can drop most anything in Web.config, which you can keep in your version control (or xcopy I guess).  https://www.iis.net/configreference  Sounds like what you really want though is Docker.  https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Other solutions include any VM software, such as VirtualBox, where you can just wrap the whole thing up into one package.  I've actually used Vagrant (which is a tool more commonly used for managing VMs during development) for deployment on Windows hosts before.  It was very easy.